# Fixed div overlays absolute with higher z-index only in one device. WHY

Tags: android, html, css, z-index

**I have the following code:**

```html
<div id="main" style="position:absolute">
  <div id="container" style="position:relative;z-index:1">
    <div id="bgd" style="position:fixed; z-index:1"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="content" style="position:absolute; z-index:15;"></div>
</div>;
```

**What do I get?**

- iOS 13 - content over bgd
- Desktop Opera 65 - content over bgd
- Android 5 WebView 67 - the same
- Android 4 WebView 75(or something about this) - the same
- Android 7 WebView 77 - the same
- IE 11 - the same

Now I bought a new phone for testing, it runs under Android 8.1, chrome is 69.

- So new phone - content behind bgd.

Please, tell me what to do. I tried a lot of things

By the way it is an Android Go smartphone

---

**Edit**

Main overflow-y is scrollable, and content exactly overflows main, therefore can be scrolled. I have put `document.getElementById("content").style.zIndex=15` in `main.onscroll`, and now it works, in my new phone as well.